# sql in clause on groupby result

Tags: sql, aggregate

given a table employee

```
Employee
id  name    salary  departmentid
1   joe 70000   1
2   jim 90000   1
3   henry   80000   2
5   max 90000   1
```

i have applied a simple query

```
SELECT name, Salary
FROM Employee
WHERE (DepartmentId, Salary) IN (SELECT DepartmentId, MAX(Salary)
                                 FROM Employee
                                 GROUP BY DepartmentId);
```

the output is given like

```
name    salary
jim 90000
henry   80000
max 90000
```

i was expecting one of jim or max row. for departmentid 1 salary for both is 90000 so max(salary) would choose one of them like in the query below but i am getting both max and jim. the result of subquery

```
SELECT name,DepartmentId, MAX(Salary) FROM Employee GROUP BY DepartmentId
```

```
name    departmentid    MAX(Salary)
jim 1           90000
henry   2           80000
```

its giving only jim not the max.can you explain me how 1st query is giving 3 result while the below query is giving only two. your input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The first query only retrieves those who fulfill the where condition. The output of this query both that fulfill departmentId = 1 and max(salary) = 90000.

The second query just brings the first occurrence, not all.

Answer (score 0):

The first query

```
SELECT name, Salary
FROM Employee
WHERE (DepartmentId , Salary) IN (
    SELECT DepartmentId, MAX(Salary)
    FROM Employee
    GROUP BY DepartmentId ) ;
```

is asking for:

- All rows from the table
- which match a subquery by `DepartmentId, Salary` of...

  - All rows in the table
  - Grouped by `DepartmentId`
  - And aggregated for the max `Salary`

So it will necessary include all tied results, as it includes *all* rows which match that `Salary`.

---

The second query uses MySQL's misfeature of allowing non-grouped columns. It's essentially the same as using a non-deterministic `ANY`.

```sql
SELECT
  ANY(name),
  DepartmentId,
  MAX(Salary)
FROM Employee
GROUP BY DepartmentId
```

So it only gets one row per `DepartmentId`.

---

Neither of these queries are great. Ideally you should use window functions for a top-n-per-group question.

Note how I've added an extra `ORDER BY` column to make it deterministic.

```sql
SELECT
  e.name,
  e.DepartmentId,
  e.Salary
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.DepartmentId ORDER BY e.Salary DESC, e.name) AS rn
    FROM Employee e
) e
WHERE e.rn = 1;
```

If you still want tied results then change `ROW_NUMBER` to `DENSE_RANK`.

Comment: ANY_VALUE is now standard ANSI/ISO SQL. (SQL:2023, optional feature T626.)

Comment: True, but it's still non-deterministic, and MySQL's weird `GROUP BY` rules confuse it more. A `FIRST_VALUE... WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY` would be more useful, but I don't think anyone has that yet.

Comment: Postgresql's `DISTINCT ON` is similar to that. Very convenient.